# Engineering very high impedance resonator with coplanar waveguides

Tags: impedance, waveguide

I have very little knowledge of electrical engineering, so please understand if my questions are somewhat trivial.

I have read that a coplanar waveguide (CPWG) acts as a lumped LC oscillator circuit, and its impedance is usually set around 50 ~ 100 Ω. My questions are:

- Is there any fundamental/practical upper limit of impedance for a single CPWG?
- Can identical CPWGs be serially connected - as we do for normal resistors, coils, and capacitors - to increase the circuit impedance?

The reason why I am asking this is that there are potential applications for the resonators with very high impedance values (say, larger than 10 kΩ), for quantum information science.

Comment: [CPWG analyser tool](https://www.microwaves101.com/calculators/864-coplanar-waveguide-calculator)

Comment: What resonant frequency are you looking for (100 Hz or 10 GHz might need different solutions)? When you say "lumped LC oscillator" do you mean "lumped LC resonator"? When you say "impedance" do you mean "characteristic impedance" (do you already know the difference between impedance and characteristic impedance)?

Comment: I am focusing on the MHz-GHz range. I think I am talking about the characteristic impedance in this case, as I want to make a direct analogy to an isolated (not driven) LC circuit.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read that a coplanar waveguide (CPWG) acts as a lumped LC oscillator circuit,

This isn't particular to coplanar waveguide. Any kind of transmission line is characterized by a an inductance and a capacitance per unit length.

The line only act as a lumped *resonator* with the given capacitance and inductance if the line is exactly 1 unit of length line (for example, if the specified capacitance is 1 pF/cm, and the length is 1 cm, then the capacitance will be 1 pF), **and** if the operating frequency is low enough for this length to be "short" (meaning the wavelength is 10x or more the line length).

> and its impedance is usually set around 50 ~ 100 Ω.

I think you are talking about the characteristic impedance here, which is the ratio of the voltage and current signal amplitudes associated with a travelling wave on the transmission line.

The characteristic impedance is not at all the same as the equivalent impedance of a given structure (for example an open or shorted stub line) constructed from the transmission line.

> The reason why I am asking this is that there are potential applications for the resonators with very high impedance values (say, larger than 10 kΩ),

It's generally not practical to make transmission lines with characteristic impedance too far outside the 10 - 400 ohm range.

But we can make a resonator using a transmission line, and the input impedance is not limited by the characteristic impedance of the structure.

You can google "coplanar waveguide resonator" or "microstrip resonator" or "coaxial resonator" to get numerous examples of ways to construct such resonators.

Comment: This may be a too basic question, but what is the difference between input impedance and the characteristic impedance?

Comment: Input impedance is the ratio of voltage to current at the input port. Characteristic impedance is the ratio of voltage to current needed to form a propagating wave along the line. The input impedance will equal the characteristic impedance only if there's no reflection returning to the input from the transmission line structure or its termination. If you can choose the termination, you can try to design for any input impedance you like, without changing the characteristic impedance.

Comment: The input impedance of a transmission line resonator isn't limited by the characteristic impedance of the structure *directly*, but it *is* limited by the characteristic impedance times the achievable Q.  So once you've optimized the materials you're using (for highest conductance and lowest losses in the insulator) you can still raise the input impedance by increasing the characteristic impedance.

Comment: May I ask why is it not practical to make transmission lines with characteristic impedance outside that range? Are there any difficulties to construct such devices?

Comment: The trace width gets too wide or too narrow.  Go play with the calculator Andy linked to. How wide a trace do you need to get below 10 ohms? How narrow do you need to get above 400 ohms? Are those numbers practical in your system?

Answer (score 0):

> I have read that a coplanar waveguide (CPWG) acts as a lumped LC oscillator circuit, and its impedance is usually set around 50 ~ 100 Ω. My questions are:

Waveguides (and transmission lines) that are correctly terminated for the job (i.e., that are *incorrectly* terminated for power coupling) act sort of like lumped LC *resonators*.  Thwack them with an appropriate pulse and you'll get a decaying response out -- but you won't get sustained oscillations without some amplifying element in there.

> Is there any fundamental/practical upper limit of impedance for a single CPWG?

Fundamental -- maybe.  Practical -- definitely.  Particularly as the frequencies get high, it gets difficult to get impedances that are outside of the 25-100 ohm range.  Ultimately this probably has something to do with the impedance of free space (\$377\Omega\$, IIRC).  In practice you'll either end up inadvertently building an antenna, or wasting all your input energy heating up the bits.

> Can identical CPWGs be serially connected - as we do for normal resistors, coils, and capacitors - to increase the circuit impedance?

Not easily -- they're usually ground referenced.  And the overall structure will be large with respect to a wavelength, which pretty much automatically means things get weird.

> The reason why I am asking this is that there are potential applications for the resonators with very high impedance values (say, larger than 10 kΩ), for quantum information science.

It could maybe be done, with difficulty, but you'll still have limited Q (2000 is probably the practical upper limit, although folks always manage to push that -- e.g. quartz crystal resonators have Qs in the tens of thousands to millions, depending on the effort expended).